# How to convert opencart into android native mobile app and iPhone

Tags: php, android, iphone, opencart

I have created a e commerce website using opencart tool and now I need to convert this into a native mobile app (Android and IOS). How can I implement this mvc structure of opencart into mobile app.

Is there any other way to convert????

Comment: You could host an opencart site and write an app that's basically a single-site web browser, but what would be the point?

Comment: there is no tool to convert a e-commerce cms to app like that and never will be but you can put into a webview and make the site responsive.
And to implement MVC learn Java to code in android and Swift3 for ios then implement your logic to do things

Comment: Even-though this is not the place to ask this kind of questions, I have a hint for you! you need to develop an app and an api to connect to your site!

Comment: I know there is an API to access the web application.but I don't know how to use it..If u can.. help me......

Comment: @PrashanthBenny ..If this is not the right place then where should I go and  ask??

Comment: @Vinny I am not sure where... but this is not the right place. Here, Only programming issues are asked. You have asked the whole development process at one shot! [Here is an aricle](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about what should be asked on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova maibe can help you.

And read this to learn more about creating app from webpages, etc
https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/

Answer (score 0):

P.S. i m developer from [opencartextionsion.in](https://www.opencartextensions.in). I m posting link of OpenCart Android App because O.P. need to get android app for his website and help O.P. to increase more sales

We created Android App that have all basic features of OpenCart website. We added some uniqueness which you can not find any where. Like **Changing Color of app from Admin panel**,**Customizing text of app**. More over app consist of Push Notification using FCM.

To get more information please visit [OpenCart Android App](https://www.opencartextensions.in/opencartandroidapp). Support: Live Chat and TIcket system

Answer (score -1):

There is no tool available to convert your website into native mobile apps. Most of the mobile app builder converts your website in to web view only. It will be very slow and not user friendly.

You must hire an android developer to build your mobile app. API is needed to sync with website.

Other wise you can use the ready made mobile app script available in the market

http://www.exlcart.com/opencart-mobileapp.html

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you link to a blog post, library, or other external resource you're involved in, [you must clearly indicate this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).